# Akka installation to use actors

Tags: scala, netbeans, akka, actor

I need to use akka and actors, what IDE should I use? Do you have any links to add some plugin? I have scala installed but I don't know what I should install. Thanks

Comment: Akka is a scala library, you don't need any ide. What ide to use with scala? Eclipse or Idea to name a few. Both workable. You can import mvn projects in eclipse and idea, there are plugins for sbt.

Comment: Based on the question you asked a few minutes ago, it sounds like you've got a basic misunderstanding of what to do. It shouldn't matter what IDE you use, as it simply helps you write the code. You need to have a *project*, which includes your code, dependencies, etc. Learn how to use [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/), as most examples/template projects for Scala will use it.

Comment: yes i use exlipse...can you explain what to do please

Answer (score 2):

As vitalli wrote, when you use Akka you use a library, so you can use any of the popular scala ides ( Eclipse, Intellij, ENSIME ... ) or anything else ( vim, emacs ... )

You should check TypeSafe Activator for very good Akka starter / template projects here:

http://typesafe.com/activator